# Append variables to object with subsequent query in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, object

Say I have two tables to store user profiles: `sm_user_profiles`(social media), and `vital_user_profiles`.

Now I want a universal object for accessing profile information.
For the sake of clarity, this object is for only one user (the logged-in user) and will not return multiple rows.

Starting with this:

```
$query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM vital_user_profiles WHERE id="1"');
$profile = $query->row();

echo $profile->email;
```

how can I combine it with this:

```
$query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM sm_user_profiles WHERE id="1"');`
$profile = $query->row();

echo $profile->facebookURL;
```

so that I can do this?

```
echo $profile->email.$profile->facebookURL;
```

I'm new to objects in PHP. Thanks in advance!

Comment: are `sm_user_profiles` and `vital_user_profiles` correlated by any id?

Comment: The auto incrementing id of vital_user_profiles corresponds to the uid column in sm, although I neglected to mention that.

Comment: i answered, please check and let me know if it works

Answer (score 0):

You can use join  on

```
sm_user_profiles.id = vital_user_profiles.id
```

where

```
vital_user_profiles.id  =1 ;
```

something like this

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can start creating an object and then in the end, return the object which has all the table's information in it. For example

```
public function build_user($uid) {
  $user_data['vital'] = $this->db->select()->from('vital_user_profiles')->where('id', $uid)->get()->row();
  $user_data['sm'] = $this->db->select()->from('sm_user_profiles')->where('id', $uid)->get()->row();
  return $user_data;
}
```

This should give you a nice object which has all the field data in it. And you can keep adding more to it. I have a big model which is doing same kind of thing where I have created a node object from 4 or 5 different tables which is database managed by Drupal and front end is done using Code Igniter. If you want I can send you the code for reference if this doesn't work for you.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [**`LEFT JOIN`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/left-join-optimization.html) function

```
$query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM `vital_user_profiles` a LEFT JOIN  `sm_user_profiles` b ON a.`id` = b.`id` WHERE a.`id` = "1"');
$profile = $query->row();
```

now we have all data we need so you can echo both values

```
echo 'Email: ' . $profile->email . ' facebook url: ' .  $profile->facebookURL;
```